# How do I install the Command Line Interface?

Tags: installation

I cannot download any startup applications or updates. I cannot trouble shoot the problem because I do not have Command Line Interface access.

Comment: Please respond to your previous question before opening a new, related one.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to install the command-line interface. You have two options:

1. From the Ubuntu Desktop, press the `Ctrl+Alt+T` keys to open a terminal (CLI).
2. Or to open a true Linux console (TTY), press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and login. To switch back to the desktop, press `Ctrl+Alt+F7` (or `Ctrl+Alt+F8`).